# ERDs: How do you indicate mutually-exclusive encounters?

Tags: database-design, erd

If you have a `character_instance` and `character` entity in an ERD for a video game, and you want to indicate that something happens when a `character` entity encounters a `character_instance` entity, how do you do that?  Here's the catch, though: a `character_instance` doesn't have the same relationship to its own `character`.  Is there any special way to indicate this complicated relationship?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Substituting another data type, you seem to be saying, "indicate that something happens when a variable of type `INTEGER` encounters a value of type `INTEGER`" (and I'm tempted to reply, we call this 'assignment' :)

Comment: @onedaywhen It wouldn't be able to encounter itself, though.  `When 1 encounters any integer but 1`, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about ERD but, if I have understood correctly, this kind of business rule is very common when considering relationships between entities e.g. consider this example in SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE People 
(
 person_ID VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE Marriages
(
 spouse_1 NOT NULL UNIQUE REFERENCES People (person_ID), 
 spouse_2 NOT NULL UNIQUE REFERENCES People (person_ID), 
 CHECK (spouse_1 < spouse_2)
);
```

In addition to enforcing the rule that a person cannot marry themselves, it also ensures that the same marriage is not entered a second time 'in the other direction' i.e. 'Albert is married to Victoria' is the same as 'Victoria is married to Albert' but only the row  `('Albert', 'Victoria') may be entered into the database.

If this is too complex for ERD, consider using another more expressive model e.g. [object role modelling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_role_modeling).

Comment: I think this is a good explanation.  I saw a way to represent it.  Have [user] connect to <friendship>, and then <friendship> connects back to [user].